# GPUの使用率を確認するCUDAのAPIはありませんか？

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, cuda

デバイスで処理を実行させている時に、ホスト側でGPUの使用率を確認するAPIはありますか？
現在nvidia-smi.exeを使って確認しているのですが、できればプログラム内で確認したいです。

開発環境は以下です。
OS:Win7Pro
VS:2012
CUDA:7.5
Device:GeForce GTX TITAN X

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ググった程度の情報ですが、 nvidia-smi と同等の情報でよければ [NVIDIA Management Library](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml) というAPIが、より詳細なパフォーマンスカウンタには [PerfKit](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-perfkit) というAPIが使えそうに見えました。

GUIベースのプロファイラだと NSight や VisualProfiler といったツールがあるとか。

Comment: unarist様
コメントありがとうございます。

NMLを調べたところ、nvidia-smiから直接データを持ってこれるようですね。
"It provides a direct access to the queries and commands exposed via nvidia-smi."

これを実装してみます。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

実行時間の計測でよろしければ、ちょっと古い記事ですが[この辺](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-implement-performance-metrics-cuda-cc/)が参考になります。

恐らく本当にやりたいことは遊んでいるコアがプログラム中のどこで発生しているかを知りたいのだと思いますが、シミュレーターでも使わない限り簡単に知ることはできません。CUDAのシミュレータは[gpuocelot](https://github.com/gtcasl/gpuocelot)が知られています。もともとLinux向けに作られていて、Windows用はまだ実験的だそうです。

コアレベルのチューニングは,CUDAではありませんが,[この記事](http://qiita.com/9_ties/items/15ab7fa198991a61a3a9)に感銘を受けました。地道な努力が必要みたいです...。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

やりたいことはご指摘の通りです。
取り敢えず現状をザックリと把握したかったのですが、そう簡単では無いのですね。

紹介して頂いた記事等を参考に地道に進めてみます。